# Could anybody explain what these lines mean or how do they work please (marked as bold)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**angular.isUndefined(attr.isEnabled) && attr.$set('isEnabled', 'true');**

**sideMenuCtrl[$scope.side]**

```
IonicModule
    .directive('ionSideMenu', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^ionSideMenus',
            scope: true,
            compile: function(element, attr) {
                angular.isUndefined(attr.isEnabled) && attr.$set('isEnabled', 'true');
                angular.isUndefined(attr.width) && attr.$set('width', '275');

                element.addClass('menu menu-' + attr.side);

                return function($scope, $element, $attr, sideMenuCtrl) {
                    $scope.side = $attr.side || 'left';

                    var sideMenu = sideMenuCtrl[$scope.side] = new ionic.views.SideMenu({
                        width: attr.width,
                        el: $element[0],
                        isEnabled: true
                    });

                    $scope.$watch($attr.width, function(val) {
                        var numberVal = +val;
                        if (numberVal && numberVal == val) {
                            sideMenu.setWidth(+val);
                        }
                    });
                    $scope.$watch($attr.isEnabled, function(val) {
                        sideMenu.setIsEnabled(!!val);
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**angular.isUndefined(attr.isEnabled) && attr.$set('isEnabled', 'true');**

This means:

*if attribute `isEnabled` is undefined, set the `isEnabled` attribute to true.*

It's a pretty standard way of chaining expressions using logical operators.

---

**var sideMenu = sideMenuCtrl[$scope.side] = new ionic.views.SideMenu({...**

This one assigns the value of `new ionic.views.SideMenu({...` to `sideMenuCtrl[$scope.side]` and a new variable named `sideMenu`.

Also pretty standard, double assignment, just like:

```
var x, y; 
x = y = 5; // now both x and y are 5
```

Comment: Thanks Shomz, the answer is really enlightening and helpful.